# Import and export data with EF Code First

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I don't want to use EF migrations.

I have SQL Server 2012 Express and the Import/Export wizard doesn't save the data in, i.e., a Excel sheet.

How can I import/export data only?

I don't want to lose the data every time the data model changes.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you simply wanting to disable the automatic migrations and handle them yourself to prevent data loss?  By default, EF won't drop and recreate your database, you need to adjust the settings to create this behavior.  However, if you want to be sure, you can simply set:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourModel>(null);
```

To set the initializer to null - if you're doing this in a web project a good place would be in the Application_Start in your global.asax.  If not, just put it somewhere really early in your app lifecycle.

You can also set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to false in your Configuration class, if you're using EF 4.3 or newer:

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
```